# Установка Linux на UEFI Acer ES1-533

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, uefi, lubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой установки Linux. Не могу установить Linux на UEFI ноутбук Acer ES1-533.

Пробовал разные дистрибутивы: Ubuntu, Mint, Lubuntu. Установка у них одинаковая и ошибка тоже. Пробовал ставить Secure Boot а режим Disabled, но без успешно. Перевести в режим Legacy невозможно. Устанавливаю с флешки, созданной через rufus.
Самый первый рез попробовал установить с автоматической разбивкой диска. Не помогло.
Разбил диск строго по инструкции "Особенности установки на платы с UEFI". При помощи GParted разбил диск на 4 раздела:

1. 100 Мб fat32
2. 50000 Мб ext4
3. 2000 Мб swap-linux
4. все остальное ext4

Потом запустил установку. Во время установки захожу в ручную разбивку и монтирую fat32 в efi, первый ext4 "/", а второй "/home".
Во время установки проходит весь процесс копирование файлов, потом устанавливаются пакеты. Но когда доходит до установки загрузчика, то зависает на 'Установка пакета grub2'. Такое чувство, вроде как установщик не видит системный раздел EFI. Сначала долго крутит, но прогрессбар на месте стоит. Даже картинки бегают. Но потом просто все зависает. Часики (курсор) перестают крутится и реагировать на движение мышки.Короче зависает.

Я пробовал ставить, что бы первый раздел был ext2 300 Mb и монтирован как "/boot". При этом вся установка прошла успешно, но после перезагрузки не увидело загрузочный раздел. Ну это и не удивительно.

Пробовал ставить на другой машине с основной ОС Windows на VirtualBox в режиме EFI. Все сделал по инструкции. Даже во время установки не выбирал ручную разбивку, а выбрал автоматическую и все установилось нормально.

Посоветуйте, может есть какой-то обходной момент.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А разметить диск автоматически пробовал? И почему обязательно включённый uefi?

Comment: Написано "Самый первый рез попробовал установить с автоматической разбивкой диска". И написано, что выключить uefi нельзя.

Comment: А, извини, надо заканчивать читать ruSO перед сном.

Comment: Есть подозрение на косяк реалзизации uefi в самом бубне. Попробуй OpenSuse и Fedora. Хотя бы ради "поехало\тоже отвалилось".

Comment: Значит я скачал и запустил Boot Repair с флешки.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25037547/

Вот эту ссылку http : // paste . ubuntu . com / 25037547/ надо показать специалистам, что бы подсказали что надо делать. Я новичок и почти ничего не понял с написанного. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, что бы у меня UEFI увидел загрузочный раздел и я смог загрузить Linux.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533 -> http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-and-M-Series-Laptops/Acer-Aspire-ES-15-ES1-533-C3UW-Legacy-BIOS-Missing/td-p/471754/page/2

Comment: все это не правильно и не поможет. Я уже нашел способ. спасибо всем.

Comment: Ну и какой способ-то?

Comment: Debian 9 нормально встаёт. Только с загрузкой нужен бубен..